# HELP need to identify what's growing

Tags: identification, roots, vines

So my veg bed was covered for the winter. After uncovering it I noticed some strange white vine type root stuff poking out. After digging a bit it transpires that these things have grown all over the bed. I've started to empty the bed so I can see where it's coming from. It looks like it's coming from the ground underneath, but can't be sure yet until fully emptied. Can any one tell me what they might be?
I have hedges near by could it be that? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czp1n.jpg)

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOfH7.jpg[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're unlikely to be roots off any shrub,hedge or tree nearby. They look horribly like bindweed roots http://home.bt.com/lifestyle/house-home/gardening/bindweed-what-is-it-11364193020893 but that can be confirmed or denied when a leaf or two appears. I take it you don't recall anything growing there prior to digging and covering it for winter?

Comment: You may be right. I did get leafy vines growing up the sides of my bed, but that's been a few years now and I usually pull them out when I can. Never noticed any roots in the soil previous years, however. It could be that the roots have decided to surface this year. Prior to covering I did notice a couple roots but ignored it which was a bad idea. The leafy vines die in the winter, and I always thought the vines grew out of the hedge. Do you know the best course of remedy?

Comment: Some suggestions in the link I posted, but to be honest, you never get rid of it - the best thing you can do now is just remove all the roots you can see, then just keep pulling it up when it starts growing again. Bindweed is, unfortunately, the gift that keeps on giving...it will grow from the tiniest root piece in the soil. Covering the  soil is probably why the roots are nearer the surface...